# How can I stopped all layers in layers movie clip when click pause button using action script-3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have use action script 3 but problem is, when I click stop button  then stop just object & graphic  not a pause movie clip, so how can I pause full screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop all MovieClips,try this

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

stopAll(stage);

private function stopAll(obj:DisplayObject):void {

    var mc:MovieClip = obj as MovieClip;
    var container:DisplayObjectContainer = obj as DisplayObjectContainer;

    if (mc) {
        mc.stop();
    }

    if (container) {

        for each (var child:DisplayObject in container) {
            stopAll(obj);
        }
    }
}
```